# Prove that entries of inverse of Hilbert Matrix are all integers using results covered in a standard linear algebra course.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, hilbert-matrices

This is an exercise question from the first chapter of Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze.
But it seems to be quite difficult to solve even with knowledge of determinants and other relevant topics.
I am curious to know if it is even possible to solve with the knowledge of the material from (a) the first chapter or
even (b) an entire course on linear algebra.

The point of this question is not only to come up with a proof. But a proof that can be arrived at with limited prior knowledge.

Comment: Have you checked out https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561 ?

Comment: thanks @KReiser

ps: Am I supposed to delete this question?

Comment: You're welcome. You're in a bit of a funny place - having a question which is sort of a cross-site duplicate is not something that's really designed for. You can delete it if you want, but it might be more interesting for you (and future readers) to self-answer the question by adapting the answer you found most helpful from MO: this position has [some historical support](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/questions-x-posted-and-answered-on-mo).